# Conda environment.yml with option for mutually exclusive packages

Tags: python, pip, conda, mxnet

I have an environment.yml with 3 conda packages and ~10 pip packages. One of the pip packages is MXNet, which have one package for CPU-only and another package for GPU only.

Ideally I want a user to only be able to install a single environment.yml file and possibly specify a cli argument --cpu to select the CPU-only version of mxnet, otherwise it defaults to the GPU-only version.

Is something like this possible?